# how to replace date component of datetime64[ns] -Pandas with another date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following `datetime64[ns]` type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` timestamps.

```
x1=pd.Timestamp('2018-04-25 00:00:00')

x2=pd.Timestamp('2020-09-02 00:53:00')
```

Is there any way I can replace the time part of `x1` with that of `x2` or vice versa.

The output should look like as follows with the `datetime64[ns]` type.

```
2018-04-25 00:53:00
```

Comment: they are two separate series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x1` and `x2` are 2 individual series and of equal indexes ,you can use the `series.dt` accessor to parse the `dt.date` from x1 and `dt.time` from x2 and bind to x1 after converting to string, then convert back to datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(x1.dt.date.astype(str) +' '+x2.dt.time.astype(str))
```

---

```
0   2018-04-25 00:53:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just normalize `x1` and add `timedelta` from `x2`

```
x1.dt.normalize() + pd.to_timedelta(x2.dt.time.astype(str))

Out[79]:
0   2018-04-25 00:53:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```